# How far should we take manufacturer meta tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

We have tags for a number of companies that make only one type of equipment or software, like [synaptics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptics), [wacom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wacom), [aptana](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aptana), and [mikrotik](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik).  There are also companies like [apc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apc) that make a range of products, but they are primarily known for one type of product and so far, that product is the only one associated with questions here.

In these cases, if the question is uniquely about that brand of the product and not generic, the manufacturer tag is unambiguous (we can assume a [synaptics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/synaptics) question is about a Synaptics touchpad device and an [apc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apc) question is about an APC UPS).

There isn't a huge number of questions associated with these tags.  Should we treat them like manufacturer meta tags and clean them up (which would likely mean renaming the tag to add a product designation), or ignore them?

Comment: A mod could probably knock over the renames of these fairly quickly, if we can come up with suggestions for each of them. For example, `[mikrotik]` -> `[mikrotik-routers]` etc

Answer (score 2):

I think we should

1. Rename the tags to clear up ambiguation.

   > [mikrotik](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik) to [mikrotik-device](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik-device)
   >
   > [wacom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wacom) to [wacom-tablet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wacom-tablet)
2. Add wiki that explains that this is specific to the device.
3. Make the [mikrotik](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik) synonym to [mikrotik-device](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mikrotik-device)

Comment: [wacom] to [wacom-tablet] was the kind of renaming I assumed if people want to clean these up.  [microtik-device], though, is still a meta tag.  Any on-topic question will be about the products, rather than the company.  So adding "device" (or "software" for a software company), still leaves it just a generic company identifier.  :-)